# Send SMS using Java

Tags: java

How I can acheive to send free sms using java . I have already used different types of gateway like way2sms, fullonsms, 160by2 ,all these some time send sms , sometime shows message sent successfully, while message not received on mobile.

Is there any java api to use?

Please some give me an idea to achieve this.

Comment: Check http://www.mvaayoo.com/ .Using currently.No mess.Assuming  with in India.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to eliminate any middle-man, you can take a look at [`SMSLib`](http://smslib.org/):

> SMSLib provides a universal texting API, which can be used for sending
>   and receiving messages via GSM modems and/or bulk sms operators.

This will require you have your own GSM Modem (which can be a phone connected through bluetooth to your machine). The advantage of this is that you have full control of what is happening.

I doubt you'll find a service which does this for free, since sending SMS's in the first place costs money.

Comment: Thanks npinti, Do you know any sms gateway provider which provide service in the cheap price like (2 paise per sms and 10 paise per sms )?

Comment: @Ashish: Not really, when I needed to do this kind of thing I used that library with a mobile phone connected through bluetooth (wasn't exactly an industrial sized application, but it worked well for what I needed).